# Количество Java Servlet для CRUD

Tags: java, servlet

делаю мини сайти на jsp +servlet+ hibernate(просто для себя). Хочу к примеру сделать CRUD новостей или амдинку. Собственно вопрос является ли плохим тоном для каждого url-pattern делать свой сервлет? или же обрабатывать в одном сервлете. Если в одном то как разграничить откуда пришел клиент?

Comment: Нет, это нормально.

Comment: Я имею ввиду делать отдельный сервлет для добавления новости, для вывода, для редактирования это норма? или подобные действия объединять в один?

Comment: Норма делать сервлет ответственный за одну сущность. Метод `doGet` для отображения сущности, `doPost` для её создания, `doPut` для изменения, `doDelete` для удаления. Один сервлет для новостей, один для комментариев, один для статей и т.п.

Comment: а вывод к примеру всех записей сущности и конкретно одной для редактирования разграничить в самом GET запросе параметров верно я понимаю(к примеру)